# Tab links not rederecting to the right page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap tabs and have added a url to each of them.

So, if someone goes to www.example.com/index.html#contact. It takes them to the right page (the contact page). 
The problem is I have a home page that links to each tab. When you click "contact" on the home page it should redirect to  www.example.com/index.html#contact, but instead it goes to the main page, which is "About us", even thought the URL at the top says www.example.com/index.html#contact and not  www.example.com/index.html#about.

I hope that made sense. 
Heres my code:

Home page: (when you click on an image it takes you to the page)

```
<div id="row1">
<a href="http://example.index.html#conference"><img src="images/About_Photo_Red.jpg" width="33%" id="about"></a>
<a href="http://example.com/index.html#conference"><img src="images/Conference_Photo_Red.jpg" width="33%" id="conference"></a>
<a href="http://example.com/index.html#sponsors"><img src="images/Sponsors_Photo_Red.jpg"width="33%" id="sponsors"></a>
</div>
```

Tabs:

```
<div class="tabs" id="navtabs">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills head-menu" id="navbar">
            <li class="active"><a href="#about" data-toggle="tab" class="scroll">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a  href="#conference" data-toggle="tab" class="scroll">Conference</a></li>
            <li><a href="#sponsors" data-toggle="tab" class="scroll">Sponsors</a></li>
            <li class="disabled"><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contactus" data-toggle="tab"class="scroll">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Java script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // add a hash to the URL when the user clicks on a tab
  $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('click', function(e) {
    history.pushState(null, null, $(this).attr('href'));
  });

  // navigate to a tab when the history changes
  window.addEventListener("popstate", function(e) {
    var activeTab = $('[href=' + location.hash + ']');
    if (activeTab.length) {
      activeTab.tab('show');
    $(this).scrollTop(0);
    } else {
      $('.nav-pills a:first').tab('show');
    }

  });
});
```

Comment: You are missing the closing anchor tag '</a>' for all your home page links.

Comment: Wow hadn't seen that, but just corrected them and still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the `popstate` event is fired only when an actual browser action is taken; calling `history.pushState` does **not** fire the event.

That said, if you take the history handler out of the event listener and into a standalone function, you can call it manually on page load (to be safe; some browsers fire a `popstate` event on pageload, and some do not) and after you push history.

Example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // add a hash to the URL when the user clicks on a tab
  $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('click', function(e) {
    history.pushState(null, null, $(this).attr('href'));
    updateTabs();
  });

  function updateTabs() {
    var activeTab = $('[href=' + location.hash + ']');
    if (activeTab.length) {
      activeTab.tab('show');
      $(window).scrollTop(0);
    } else {
      $('.nav-pills a:first').tab('show');
    }
  }

  // navigate to a tab when the history changes
  window.addEventListener("popstate", updateTabs);

  // make sure the correct tab is set on pageload
  updateTabs();  
});
```